# Deploy error Cloud Functions - Firebase Deploy

Tags: firebase, npm, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Error returning when executing the firebase deploy command. I tried some configuration options, but none worked.

**Error Firebase Deploy**

```
=== Deploying to '###'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint

> functions@ lint C:\usCloud\functions
> tslint --project tsconfig.json


WARNING: C:/usCloud/functions/src/index.ts:13:10 - bodyParser is deprecated.
WARNING: C:/usCloud/functions/src/index.ts:14:10 - bodyParser is deprecated.

Running command: npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run build

> functions@ build C:\usCloud\functions
> tsc

node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:23:1 - error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: DocumentData, UpdateData, Firestore, GeoPoint, Transaction, WriteBatch, WriteResult, DocumentReference, DocumentSnapshot, QueryDocumentSnapshot, OrderByDirection, WhereFilterOp, Query, QuerySnapshot, DocumentChangeType, CollectionReference, FieldValue, FieldPath, Timestamp, v1beta1, v1, OK, CANCELLED, UNKNOWN, INVALID_ARGUMENT, DEADLINE_EXCEEDED, NOT_FOUND, ALREADY_EXISTS, PERMISSION_DENIED, RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED, FAILED_PRECONDITION, ABORTED, OUT_OF_RANGE, UNIMPLEMENTED, INTERNAL, UNAVAILABLE, DATA_LOSS, UNAUTHENTICATED, FirebaseFirestore

23 declare namespace FirebaseFirestore {
   ~~~~~~~

  node_modules/firebase-functions-helper/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:25:1
    25 declare namespace FirebaseFirestore {
       ~~~~~~~
    Conflicts are in this file.

node_modules/firebase-functions-helper/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:25:1 - error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: DocumentData, UpdateData, Firestore, GeoPoint, Transaction, WriteBatch, WriteResult, DocumentReference, DocumentSnapshot, QueryDocumentSnapshot, OrderByDirection, WhereFilterOp, Query, QuerySnapshot, DocumentChangeType, CollectionReference, FieldValue, FieldPath, Timestamp, v1beta1, v1, OK, CANCELLED, UNKNOWN, INVALID_ARGUMENT, DEADLINE_EXCEEDED, NOT_FOUND, ALREADY_EXISTS, PERMISSION_DENIED, RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED, FAILED_PRECONDITION, ABORTED, OUT_OF_RANGE, UNIMPLEMENTED, INTERNAL, UNAVAILABLE, DATA_LOSS, UNAUTHENTICATED, FirebaseFirestore

25 declare namespace FirebaseFirestore {
   ~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:23:1
    23 declare namespace FirebaseFirestore {
       ~~~~~~~
    Conflicts are in this file.

node_modules/firebase-functions-helper/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:168:5 - error TS2374: Duplicate string index signature.

168     [key: string]: any; // Accept other properties, such as GRPC settings.
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 3 errors.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! functions@ build: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\##\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-26T16_49_58_562Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code2
```

**My index.ts**

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as firebaseHelper from 'firebase-functions-helper/dist';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore;

const app = express();
const main = express();

main.use(bodyParser.json());
main.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
main.use('/api/v1', app);

const trackerCollection = 'tracker';
export const webApi = functions.https.onRequest(main);

app.patch('/tracker/:tid', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        await firebaseHelper.firestore.updateDocument(db, trackerCollection, req.params.tid, req.body);
        res.status(200).send('Update Success');
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(204).send('Patch Error');
    }
})
```

**tsconfig.json - Original condition, unchanged.**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
}
```

**package.json - Original condition, unchanged.**

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1",
    "firebase-functions-helper": "^0.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I changed some typescript settings, but it didn't work. I returned everything to its original state.

Comment: Your dependencies are all somewhat old.  I suggest modernizing everything, perhaps by starting over with a new template created by `firebase init`.

Comment: I've found some information that may help you find the cause of errors.

Uncaught exceptions produced by your function will appear in Stackdriver Error Reporting. Note that some uncaught exceptions, for example, those thrown asynchronously, can cause a cold start on a future function invocation. This reduces function performance.

I found this information here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/reporting-errors

Comment: @DougStevenson I restarted the project and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, issuing the command firebase init resolved this scenario.