# Deploy Firebase Cloud Functions, namespace problems

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy a firebase function following this tutorial: `https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?gen=2nd`.

My code looks like the following:

```
import {logger} from "firebase-functions";
import {onDocumentCreated} from "firebase-functions/v2/firestore";

exports.makeuppercase = onDocumentCreated("/configurations/{id}", (event) => {
 // Grab the current value of what was written to Firestore.
 const original = event.data?.data().original;

 // Access the parameter `{documentId}` with `event.params`
 logger.log("test", event.params, original);
});
```

My `package.json` looks like the following:

```
{
"name": "functions",
"scripts": {
"lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
"build": "tsc",
"build:watch": "tsc --watch",
"serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
"shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
"start": "npm run shell",
"deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
"logs": "firebase functions:log"
},
"engines": {
"node": "16"
},
"main": "lib/index.js",
"dependencies": {
"firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
"firebase-functions": "^3.18.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.12.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.0",
"eslint": "^8.9.0",
"eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
"firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
"typescript": "^4.5.4"
},
"private": true
}
```

After running the command `firebase deploy`. I get the following errors: `node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:23:1 - error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: DocumentData, UpdateData, Firestore, GeoPoint, Transaction, BulkWriter, BulkWriterError, WriteBatch, SetOptions, WriteResult, DocumentReference, DocumentSnapshot, QueryDocumentSnapshot, OrderByDirection, WhereFilterOp, Query, QuerySnapshot, DocumentChangeType, CollectionReference, CollectionGroup, QueryPartition, FieldValue, FieldPath, Timestamp, BundleBuilder, v1beta1, v1, OK, CANCELLED, UNKNOWN, INVALID_ARGUMENT, DEADLINE_EXCEEDED, NOT_FOUND, ALREADY_EXISTS, PERMISSION_DENIED, RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED, FAILED_PRECONDITION, ABORTED, OUT_OF_RANGE, UNIMPLEMENTED, INTERNAL, UNAVAILABLE, DATA_LOSS, UNAUTHENTICATED, FirebaseFirestore`

It seems like there is a namespace clash. I found the following entries discussing a similar problem (posted 1-3 years ago). I am still surprised the above error occurs since I am following the firebase tutorial.

1. [Error: TS6200 with Firestore dependancies - unable to compile angular project after running updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74224075/error-ts6200-with-firestore-dependancies-unable-to-compile-angular-project-af)
2. [Deploy error Cloud Functions - Firebase Deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63602466/deploy-error-cloud-functions-firebase-deploy)

Has any of you any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Instead of saying that you're following a tutorial, write out the actual steps that anyone can follow to create and deploy a project that ends in this state. The idea is to allow everyone to see exactly what you've done and duplicate it for themselves.

Comment: You're not using the latest version of `firebase-admin` and `firebase-functions` packages. If this is a package problem, maybe they are already fixed. I recommend you using [node-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) package to update your dependencies to latests available versions

Comment: As NoNam4 has covered, `firebase-admin` v10.0.2 was released in Jan 2022. The latest version is v12.0.0 as of Dec 2023. [v12.0.0 Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node#version_1200_-_07_december_2023)